# Can I create views in AWS Lake Formation

Tags: aws-lake-formation

I have created two tables in Lake Formation. For the users, I would like to create a view by joining these two tables. Is that possible in Lake Formation?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to [create view](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-view.html) in your query engines like Amazon Athena (SQL). Note that this view is not usable in another engine like Spark.